# Geom use in R to show distrabution of a single variable

Tags: r

Which Geom functions can you use to make a plot showing the distribution of a single variable?

Comment: try `hist(c(1,2,3,4))` or `boxplot(c(1,2,3,4))`

Answer (score 0):

Use a histogram or density or boxplot, for instance, in combination with `ggplot`

```
  geom_histogram()
  geom_boxplot()
  geom_density()
```